# Dualboot Fedora 20 + Windows 8 on separate drives

Tags: windows-8, boot, fedora, grub, uefi

Well hello there, I have a little problem with my dualboot setup.

So I decided to dualboot Windows (for gaming-puposes) and Fedora (for everything else), and I also decided to give them separate drives - a 120GB SSD for Fedora and a 500GB HDD for Windows.

So I first installed Windows on the HDD (making sure to boot the installer-CD in UEFI-mode), then I installed Fedora on the SSD (again, making sure I was booting in UEFI-mode) - btw I used the auto-partition feature of the installer - and rebooted.

On first glance everything looks fine - GRUB gives me the possibility to boot Fedora, Fedora Rescue Mode, as well a "Windows Bootmanager"

Booting Fedora works fine but if I choose the Windows bootmanager, I get the following error message:

`error: file '/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found`

`error: you need to load the kernel first`

However, if I set my motherboard to load the Windows Bootmanager directly, Windows starts up fine (doesn't give me the option to start Fedora though), so I assume it's a problem with my GRUB.

Any suggestions?

P.S. my storage mode is set to AHCI - I somewhere read that might make a difference...

Comment: Can you check that you have a unique EFI partition, and not one on each drive ? It should be a small (~100MB) FAT32 partition. Fedora might have created a second one instead of using the one created by Windows. I once made a similar installation with Windows 7, but installing the Linux first and Windows afterwards. Worked like a charm.